# Grass gis - 3D data set interpolate to 3D raster

Tags: grass-gis, interpolation, 3d-model

I have a dataset of 70,000 points and I would like to interpolate the properties as a 3D raster.  I have created 'slices' of properties each meter of elevation in the model domain; approx: 200 slices.

The format of the dataset is as follows:
BH, EastingNad83, NorthingNad83, Elevation, Property(numerber),Property(text)

(coordinates are in UTM)
The data points are located along boreholes (approx 5000).

I am able to import the data set in Grass Gis. However, I am unable to create the 3D raster using V.Vol.Rst.  Is the data set too large for this module?

Comment: Did you also set the 3rd dimension of the computational region with g.region (b - bottom and t - top parameters)? See https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/g.region.html#changing-extent-and-raster-resolution-in-3d

Comment: I am wondering if as the data points are stacked above each other (vertical data set) then it just imports one layer (or elevation slice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was an issue of g.region where you have to provide a value for the resolution for each parameter, and resolution should match if they are referring to the same direction.